# Current Keyboard Type iOS7

Tags: ios

Is there a way in `iOS7` to get the current keyboard type? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UITextInputMode/activeInputModes) state that `[UITextInputMode currentTextInput]` is deprecated and they offer no alternative...

Comment: Can you use `+activeInputModes`?

Comment: @Tim well that's an array of the active keyboard inputs, but it's ordering never changes. So I don't think so. Thanks for the suggestion though